# Solve $\int \frac{2x}{(x^2+x+1)^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Solve
$$\int \frac{2x}{\left(x^2+x+1\right)^2}dx$$

I tried using integrating in parts by using the partial fraction method where the rational function is split into 
$$\frac{Ax+B}{x^2+x+1} + \frac{Cx+D}{(x^2+x+1)^2}$$
But then I just get the original formula with A=$0$ B=$0$ C=2 and D=$0$...

Please help!

Comment: You can use the subsitution $y=x^2+x+1$.

Comment: Yes, it works. One can obtain the step-by-step solution here: https://www.integralrechner.de/ (unfortunately only in german but should still be clear)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$\dfrac{d(x^2+x+1)}{dx}=?$

$$\dfrac{2x}{(x^2+x+1)^2}=\dfrac{2x+1}{(x^2+x+1)^2}-\dfrac1{(x^2+x+1)^2}$$

As $4(x^2+x+1)=(2x+1)^2+3$

how about starting with $2x+1=\sqrt3\tan y$

**See also** : [Trigonometric substitutions](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/integration/trigsub/trigsub.html), [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution)

Comment: I don't understand it... how come your hint contain a derivative and how can i use tan?

Comment: @DylanJoeSmith, Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I solved it now thanks! :)